# Есть ли возможность отдельно получить нужный файл, приходящий браузеру после отправления запроса?

Tags: python, c#, selenium-webdriver

Перед тем, как парсить сайт, пробовал отследить, что приходит в fiddler, но там большое количество переходов, поэтому бросил затею.
При отправке get запроса по ссылке с помощью c# и HttpClient приходит некий js код, вперемешку с html тегами 
`using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,"https://megamarket.ru/catalog/zhenskaya-odezhda/"); using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);`

Также использовал python и selenium с webdriver, чтобы получить хоть что-то вразумительное, но в этом случае приходит километровый текст, там тоже намешаны html страницы и js код, при этом это спарсить через bs4 невозможно.

'''
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

```
driver.maximize_window()

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "html")))
    with open('source-page.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(driver.page_source)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

'''
В режиме разработчика есть путь к файлу html страницы во вкладке source, top и конкретная страница, можно ли как-то средствами selenium просто скачать нужную страницу из браузера, а не получать километровую мешанину?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конкретно скажите, что вам надо из данных на этом сайте, так будет проще, чем искать какие-то там файлы...

Comment: Изучил я сайт. При первом посещении вам дают JS скрипт, где есть функция `process()`, которая выполняет ряд преобразований и перенаправляет вас либо на капчу, либо на сайт с определенными куками, а именно `spid` и `spsc`, с этими куками первым запросом выполняется GET запрос на адрес `/api/fl/idw-smm`, который дает еще одну куку `cfidsw-smm`, ну а уже с этими куками идет POST запрос на адрес `/api/mobile/v1/securityService/session/start`, который еще дает вам несколько кук. Имея всю эту портянку уже идут запросы на получение данных (`.../search`), которые вам и надо получать.

Comment: Также раз в пару сек, кука `cfidsw-smm` обновляется (отправляется POST запрос на `/api/fl` с указанием всех ID и токенов). Собственно, тут проблема в начале, нужно как-то выполнить JS скрипт, который даст эти две куки, которые уже потом подставить куда надо. Решите это, скорей всего получите данные, но не факт, там походу есть одноразовые куки, ибо при копирование в тот-же Postman сайт отказывается уже общаться.

Comment: Из файлов на сайте я бы хотел просто получить позиции товаров, цены и скидки. Насчет куки у меня тоже опасения были, тут скорее всего возникнут с ними сложности. Поэтому я думал, есть ли возможность просто открыть сайт через браузер с selenium, чтобы скрипты через него выполнились, и скачать нужный файл с помощью webdriver. Вот есть пример https://github.com/twentyxic/SMM_parser, где через webdriver сохраняется  информация в файл source_page.html, но там месиво из куки, скриптов и веб страницы. Есть возможность сохранять только файлы с расширением .html из браузера?

Comment: Так в этом месиве нужные вам данные, разве нет? Начиная с `window.__APP__=` идет большой JSON, в котором и есть все товары страницы, аналогичный JSON вы получите и через API (`/search`). Найдите конец этого JSON и десериализуйте просто в нужный класс, все.

Comment: Дело в том, что нужно еще отфильтровать по цене, и, как я понимаю, фильтр бессмысленно передавать в url, потому что по умолчанию открывается всегда страница без фильтров. Видимо, нужно через selenium выбрать фильтры, а потом уже этот вариант страницы парсить

Comment: Ну, тогда у вас не остается вариантов, мучайте API, пытайтесь получить нужные ключи для него. Яб поступил так: что-то, что исполнит первые JS запустил-бы (можно и селениум), как только на руках появляются `spid` и `spsc`, начал-бы самостоятельно вызывать все запросы, пока не собрались бы все нужные куки, а уже с ними отправлял нужный запрос на `/search`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://megamarket.ru/catalog/zhenskaya-odezhda/")
    source = page.content()

    with open('source-page.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(source)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    items = soup(class_="catalog-item catalog-item-desktop ddl_product catalog-item_enlarged")
    for x in items: print(x.find(class_="item-title").text.strip())
    browser.close()

# Водолазка Panda, белый
# ...
# Комплект носков Cotton & Quality, разноцветный
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо добавить пару комментариев к ответу